# db_select usage in class and returned object

Tags: database

I'd like to use db_select in a static public function of a certain class. The query should be a base query, which may then be customized in the calling function. Returning the result sets seems to work, but I'd like to return the drupal db_select-object for further usage. Here is some example code:

```
class foo{ 
 public static function get_query() {
  $query = db_select('bar', 'b'); 
  return $query;
 }
} 
function test() { 
  $qobj = foo::get_query(); 
  $qobj->fields('b', array('id', 'name'));
  $result = $qobj->execute();
  ...
}
```

The returned object seems not to be a db_select object, which can be edited further more.
Do I have to create a dummy db_select and pass the reference of this object to the static function.

Thank you.

Sven

Comment: *"The returned object seems not to be a db_select object"* - could you please post a result of `dpr` or `var_dump` called on a returned object? That way you (and we) would *know*, not only *seem*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such class as `db_select`, but your code will return a valid `SelectQuery`.

```
class foo{ 
 public static function get_query() {
  $query = db_select('bar', 'b'); 
  return $query;
 }
} 
function test() { 
  $qobj = foo::get_query(); 

  // Get type of object
  dpm(get_class($qobj));

  // Alter the query string and make sure it has been altered
  $qobj->fields('b');
  dpm((string) $qobj);

}
test();
```

The first Devel output for the above is `SelectQuery`, as expected. The second is the following query string:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM 
{bar} b
```

Now add another function to the mix:

```
function test2() { 
  $qobj = foo::get_query(); 
  $qobj->fields('b', array('x'));
  dpm((string) $qobj);
}
```

Run that in the same page request, and you get this query string

```
SELECT b.x AS x
FROM 
{bar} b
```

So your code works exactly as you've specified that it should do.

If you're expecting something else to happen, it would be a good idea to detail that in the question.